# Image Reading using Arduino/C

Tags: bitmap, arduino, image-manipulation

How can we read a black and white bitmap image of 96 by 56 pixels into an array of corresponding zeros and ones from SD Card by using SD Card shield with arduino.

Answer (score 1):

For instance using the SD library:

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD

You just have to format the SD in FAT16 or FAT32 and save the image on the SD in BMP format. Then you have to read it in the arduino: BMP files save the pixel data as raw bytes (you just have to skip the header). Here is the reference for the BMP header:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

This way you will be able to modify the image in the arduino